# Extracting data from a JSON database (Python 3)

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to write a program that loads data from a JSON database into a Python list of dictionary and adds all of the number of times the mean temperature was above versus below freezing. However, I am struggling to extract information from the database successfully/ I am concerned my algorithim is off. My plan:
1) define a function that loads data from the json file.
2) define a function that extracts information from the file
3) use that extracted information to tally the number of times the temp was above or below freezing

```
import json

def load_weather_data(): #function 1: Loads data
    with open("NYC4-syr-weather-dec-2015.json", encoding = 'utf8') as w: #w for weather
        data = w.read()
        weather = json.loads(data)
        print(type(weather))
        return weather

def extract_temp(weather): #function 2: Extracts information on weather
    info = {}
    info['Mean TemperatureF'] = weather['Mean TemperatureF']#i keep getting a type error here
    return info

print("Above and blelow freezing")
weather = load_weather_data()
info = extract_temp(weather)
above_freezing = 0
below_freezing = 0
for temperature in weather: # summing the number of times the weather was above versus below freezing
    if info['Mean Temperature'] >32:
        above_freezing=above_freezing+1
    elif info['mean temperature']<32:
        below_freezing = below_freezing +1

print(above_freezing)
print(below_freezing)
```

If you have any ideas, please let me know! Thank you.

Comment: Can you post sample data - abbreviated!!! - and the full stack trace? What was the result of `print(type(weather))`?

Comment: My guess is that `weather` is a list and you really wanted to extract temperature from each `temperature` object as you go through the list.

Comment: And what if its exactly 32 degrees?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to extract temperature from the `weather` list one time before starting the loop when really you should be doing it for each temperature object in the loop. You haven't posted sample data, but I think that `weather` is a `list` and you are trying to use it as a `dict`. Below is a fix with a couple of other changes for tidiness.

```
import json

# fixed: call with filename so that the function works on other files
def load_weather_data(filename): #function 1: Loads data
    with open(filename, encoding = 'utf8') as w: #w for weather
        # fixed: fewer steps
        return json.load(w)

# fixed: not needed, doesn't simply anything
#def extract_temp(weather): #function 2: Extracts information on weather
#    info = {}
#    info['Mean TemperatureF'] = weather['Mean TemperatureF']#i keep getting a type error here
#    return info

print("Above and blelow freezing")

weather = load_weather_data("NYC4-syr-weather-dec-2015.json")
above_freezing = 0
below_freezing = 0

for temperature in weather: # summing the number of times the weather was above versus below freezing
    if info['Mean Temperature'] > 32:
        above_freezing += 1
    # fixed: capitalized above... so assuming it should be here too
    elif info['Mean Temperature'] < 32:
        below_freezing += 1

print(above_freezing)
print(below_freezing)
```

Comment: Thank you for your attempt. I changed info to weather but I'm getting a type error. Specifically, "list indices must be integers or slices, not str". I've also tried using w['Mean Temperature'] but have not had any luck. Please let me know if you have ideas on this as well. thank you.

Comment: These are the details of your data set. Which items are lists verses dicts; what are the field names. Since you haven't posted the data, there isn't enough to go on!